# I want to add list of buttons in the same line in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

What I want is to add list of buttons (the number come from the service) to a uiview programmatically, so I think is I have to check if the space between the last button and the end of UIView is enough to add button or I have to go to the next line? Right?

Could you please help me on that?

Thanks,

Comment: use a collectionView instead..

Comment: as the previous comment suggested use a UICollectionView with a horizontal scrolling flow layout. It will layout the buttons out for you the way you want to

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the problem?

Comment: I tried the UICollectionview but the problem is because the width of the button is dynamic so I dont have a fix space between cell, for example in a row I have 3 button but in another I have 2 buttons so the space between is not equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Button added with auto layout constraints so it will work the same in all size classes :)

```
var lastButton : UIButton? = nil

        for i in 0...5 {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
            button.sizeToFit()
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            if i == 0 {
                let viewComponents : [String : Any] = ["button" : button]
                self.view.addSubview(button)
                let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(20)-[button]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewComponents)
                let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(8)-[button]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewComponents)

                self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
                self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                lastButton = button
            }
            else {
                if (lastButton != nil) {
                    self.view.addSubview(button)
                    let viewComponents : [String : Any] = ["button" : button, "lastButton" : lastButton!]
                    if (lastButton!.frame.maxX + 8 + button.bounds.size.width) > self.view.bounds.size.width {
                        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-(8)-[button]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewComponents)
                        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[lastButton]-(8)-[button]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewComponents)

                        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
                        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        lastButton = button
                    }
                    else {
                        self.view.addSubview(button)
                        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "[lastButton]-(8)-[button]", options: [.alignAllTop], metrics: nil, views: viewComponents)

                        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        lastButton = button
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @houssam-hammoud : Glad it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

The idea is using UICollectionView. You can implement it with following:

1. Subclass UICollectionViewCell to make your own cell which has the button
2. Subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout, override 
   layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) which provides the attributes for each cell. You may need to pre-calculate the frame of button or cell in function prepare()
3. Create UICollectionView instance with the collectionviewLayout you just subclassed.